# Xcode9 seems doesn't support 3rd llvm compiler?

Tags: llvm, xcode9

Replace the default Apple-LLVM with the LLVM 5.0 downloaded from llvm.org.
and compiling, xcode thrown an error:

```
clang-5.0: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

Xcode8 is OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Clang 5.0-only issue. I am having the same issue with a custom Clang 3.9.
Xcode 9 has introduced a custom argument that a normal Clang does not support:

> The `-index-store-path` argument does not exist in Clang 5.0 and it gets discarded without any error message. The problem is that its argument, a folder, is not discarded, and Clang considers it as a source file. This leads to the following errors:
>
> - `cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files` (this happens if a `-o` argument is passed)
> - `error reading '<PATH>'` (this can be observed when running the "normalized" version of the clang command, generated via the -### flag)

Source: [Facebook/infer: Remove unsupported `index-store-path` argument from clang commands](https://github.com/facebook/infer/commit/17cc5ec7bec1ef0d10fc3461f089384ee7e51c7f).

---

In my custom toolchain based on Clang/CMake/Xcode I use a [wrapper around clang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355809/598057) in which I just cut off this argument and the folder passed to it and everything works fine.

Comment: This is in the process of being upstreamed: https://reviews.llvm.org/D39050