# What is the Objective-C equivalent of SWIFT_EXEC user-defined setting?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, llvm

I used to intercept the swift files before compilation by adding a user defined setting ("SWIFT_EXEC") in the target's build settings in Xcode.

SWIFT_EXEC points to my custom script which internally modifies some Swift files and then calls the original `swiftc` compiler.

Is there a way to achieve the same for Objective-C files? (I want to intercept the .h and .m files before compilation)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327952/how-can-i-force-xcode-to-use-a-custom-compiler?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize using the `CC` build setting.