# Using GCC 4.2 in an Xcode 8.3.3 Project

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, gcc, clang

I want to use the tree_policy STL data structure, but the Clang compiler doesn't support that. I followed some other peoples' advice but the option for GCC 4.2 doesn't appear in build options. I am using C++11.

[image: screenshot of Xcode build options]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327952/how-can-i-force-xcode-to-use-a-custom-compiler.