# How can I override the path for clang for SourceKit?

Tags: xcode, clang, sourcekit

In Xcode, I can easily override which clang path to use with `CC=...` in a .xcconfig file. However, this setting doesn't seem to apply to SourceKit. Any ideas how to use a custom clang path for SourceKit?

Comment: One workaround, it seems, is to replace `clang` in the toolchain with a shim at that path. Hacky but seems to work.

Comment: Maybe try [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355809/8740349)